# Parsing user input into Recycler view

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm new to android and I'm trying to let the user input his data using EditText and display it using recycler View. is that possible?

here is the recycler view code I tested by inputting strings to it and it works fine

public class MedicineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<Medicine> medicineItems;

public MedicineAdapter() {
    super();
    medicineItems = new ArrayList<Medicine>();
    Medicine item = new Medicine();
    item.setTitle("Panadol Extra");
    item.setNotes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing");
    item.setThumbnail(R.drawable.panadol_extra);
    item.setNextD(3);
    item.setDose("afternoon");

    medicineItems.add(item);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.medicine_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Medicine item = medicineItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    viewHolder.tvNotes.setText(item.getNotes());
    viewHolder.tvNextD.setText(Double.toString(item.getNextD()));
    viewHolder.tvDose.setText(item.getDose());
    viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.getThumbnail());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return medicineItems.size();
}

//    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView tvTitle;
    public TextView tvNotes;
    public TextView tvDose;
    public TextView tvNextD;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mthumbnail);
        tvNotes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tvNextD = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nextDose);
        tvDose = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dose);
    }


}
```

}

Now I'm trying to use EditText to set the medicine name, notes, and dosage from user input

public class AddMedicineActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_medicine);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

    // Adding to the toolbar back button to be enable to return to home screen
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void onClick(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MedicineAdapter.class);

    final EditText nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    final EditText notesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notesInput);
    final EditText doseInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doseInput);

    String userName = nameInput.getText().toString();
    String userNotes = notesInput.getText().toString();
    String userDose = doseInput.getText().toString();

    i.putExtra("nameMassege",userName);
    i.putExtra("notesMassege",userNotes);
    i.putExtra("doseMassege",userDose);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

for some reasons when I try to use getintent().getExtras(); in the recycler view activity to use the intent it gives me error

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is possible. What exactly is stopping you ? Give more details so that we can help you accordingly.

Comment: Add a recycler view to your activity. RecyclerView takes a dataAdapter that converts the data that your want to display into something RecyclerView can understand and handle. You can find code for it at a lot of places. Then on your EditText input, just call the notifydatasetchaged() of the recyclerView's dataAdapter.

Comment: I did the recycleView and I was able to add strings to it.
I just I don't know how to parse editText to it.

Comment: update your question with the code. Will help you change it as per your need.

Comment: Kindly add other parts of the code also. And also explain what you want to do with your edittext

Comment: Done, do you want me to add the xml to?
thank you very much for your concern

Comment: What do you want the startActivity(i); to do? include the second medicine details to the already existing list? or just open a view where you will show the second medicine details? Your usage of RecyclerView is ambiguous, kindly check the docs for RecyclerView and make sure if you are using it right.

Comment: I want to include the medicine data to the already existing list

Comment: I will do right now thank you